# Symfony 2 form theme with choice field

Tags: php, forms, symfony, twig

I have problem. I want to do choices country with flag ico but I don't know how to create custom theme for form choice filed.

I created test form :

```
->add('name', 'choice', array('choices' =>array('en' => 'England', 'de' => 'Deutshland')))
```

Next in my view I try

```
{% block _send_name_widget %}
    <select>
        {% for f in form %}
            {{ loop.index }}
        {%endfor%}
    </select>
{% endblock%}

{{ form_widget(form.name) }}
```

And in my html code I've got:

```
<select>
 1
 2
</select>

<select>
</select>
```

Could you tell me why? 
How can I render only one select with parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override the choice template:

```
{% block choice_widget_options %}
{% spaceless %}
    {% for group_label, choice in choices %}
        {% if choice is iterable %}
            <optgroup label="{{ group_label|trans({}, translation_domain) }}">
                {% set options = choice %}
                {{ block('choice_widget_options') }}
            </optgroup>
        {% else %}
            <option value="{{ choice.value }}"{% if choice is selectedchoice(value) %} selected="selected"{% endif %}>
                  <img src="/images/flags/{{ choice.label }}.jpg" />
                  {{ choice.label|trans({}, translation_domain) }}
            </option>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock choice_widget_options %}
```

more info about form theming in the [Symfony2 docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html#cookbook-form-theming-methods)

Comment: Thank you for fast answer.

I used your example but I've error:
Variable "options" does not exist

Comment: it exists. read the docs carefully and implement the theming like there

Comment: Hi, 

I use sample from there 
https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/Resources/views/Form/form_div_layout.html.twig
and I read documentation but I've got error all the time.

    {% for group_label, choice in options %}

Variable "options" does not exist


I don't know where I should search error.
Someone can help me?

Comment: The late answer by @VaN clears things up; the var is called `choices`.

Answer (score 3):

The variable "options" didn't exist in my choice_widget_options template. The fact is that "options" IS NOT the correct name of the variable. If you take a look at `\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Resources\views\Form\choice_widget_options.html.php`, you'll find Symfony use a variable called 'choices'.

The corrected version of the previous code is :

```
{% block choice_widget_options %}
{% spaceless %}
    {% for group_label, choice in choices %}
        {% if choice is iterable %}
            <optgroup label="{{ group_label|trans({}, translation_domain) }}">
                {% set options = choice %}
                {{ block('choice_widget_options') }}
            </optgroup>
        {% else %}
            <option value="{{ choice.value }}"{% if choice is selectedchoice(value) %} selected="selected"{% endif %}>
              <img src="/images/flags/{{ choice.label }}.jpg" />
              {{ choice.label|trans({}, translation_domain) }}
        </option>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock choice_widget_options %}
```